# I have a movie that no longer plays on iTunes or my iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad

A couple of years ago, I downloaded the movie Sita Sings the Blues, put it on iTunes on my Mac and on my iPad.    A few months ago, I got errors synchronizing my iTunes with my iPad and traced it down to this movie.   I deleted it from my iPad and went to http://www.sitasingstheblues.com/ and downloaded it in the various versions available.

Download versions are:

- All downloadable formats at Archive.org
- 1080p (HD) (4GB QuickTime H.264 .mp4)
- 720p (HD) (3GB Qucktime H.264 .mp4)
- 480p (SD) (1GB QuickTime H.264 .mp4)
- 640x360 700MB XviD download (burnable to CD-R/RW)

Trying to load these onto iTunes locked up iTunes.   I can play this movie with various apps on my Mac, and convert them into .mov, .avi & mv4.   But dragging any version to iTunes gets me the beach ball and I have to force quit iTunes.

My iTunes/iPad have other movies (.mov, .mp4, & m4v) that work fine.

Any suggestions on what my next step should be?

Answer (score 1):

Can you upload it to iCloud Drive? You might be able to then try playing on the iPad directly without having to go through iTunes. If you have VLC on your iPad it should be able to play almost any file that you throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

Which ipad model do you own,different iPad model has different playback settings such as video codec, bit rate, frame rate, resolution and audio codec, bit rate, sample rate and channels settings.

Comment: Since I can't load it onto iTunes, I haven't been able to test whether my 9.7" iPad pro can play the movie.